# Is there something like a rowid or a work-around for it in Semantic MediaWiki?

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries

explains how to do Queries in [Semantic MediaWiki](http://www.semantic-mediawiki.org)

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]] [[Population::+]]
|?Population
|format=table
}}
```

is an example for such a query.

Now it would be nice to have a column that shows a running index / rowid as
[shown here](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/User:WolfgangFahl/Workdocumentation_2015-11-18_WF).

**How could this be done?**

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your mockup of the desired answer. More specifically than rowid, the numbers in your first column are in fact the alphabetical ascending rank of the city name, since the rows keep their numbers even if the table is resorted by some other column. so going on that assumption, yes there's a hackish way to accomplish that.

The hackish solution is hackish for lots of reasons, one of them is that it assumes the pages you want the query to return use a template. In that template, you want to set 2 properties.

The first property is something like

```
[[CityName::{{FULLPAGENAME}}]]
```

The reason we want that is to put the page title in a property which SMW can play around with. Why will become apparent now.

The second property will look something like this:

```
[[CityAlphaRank::{{#ask: [[CityName::<{{FULLPAGENAME}}]] | format=count}}]]
```

What that line does is, it counts how many page titles are alphabetically before the current one (including the current one) and outputs the number. AKA the alphabetical ranking.

Only thing that's left for you is to modify your query so it uses these two new properties. would probably look something like:

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]] [[Population::<300000]]
|mainlabel=-
| ?CityAlphaRank
| ?CityName
| ?Population
| format=table
}}
```

Note, this strikes me as ugly and hackish, and while devising this solution I managed to coax quite a few white error pages of death out of my test system. Therefore this solution is very likely to be deeply inadvisable, but it does work. :)